# What is the discrete analogue of the Liouville–Neumann series?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, integral-equations

The [Liouville-Neumann seres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%E2%80%93Neumann_series) is a manner of writing the solution to a Fredholm integral equation as an infinite series. What is the discrete analogue finite dimensional matrices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply: if you want to solve $(I - \lambda A) x = y$, and $\lambda$ is sufficiently small, then $I - \lambda A$ can be inverted using a geometric series

$$x = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \lambda^k A^k y.$$

The Liouville-Neumann series is exactly this but for $A$ an integral operator instead of a matrix.

Comment: Two questions. How small does $\lambda$ have to be? How come in the integral version, there is no restriction on $\lambda$?

Comment: @becko: 1) Small enough so that the series converges, which happens if and only if $\lambda^k A^k y \to 0$. Without any conditions on $y$, this means you want $|\lambda| < \frac{1}{\nu(A)}$ where $\nu(A)$ is the spectral radius of $A$ (absolute value of the largest eigenvalue in absolute value). 2) This is just wrong and I have edited the page. With no restriction on $\lambda$ there is no reason the series should converge. You can see a condition on $\lambda$ stated explicitly in Theorem 4.6 here: http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~wparnell/MT34032/34032_IntEqunsNeumannSeries.pdf

Comment: Thank you, and good job editing the page. It was missing this.